# SQL Statement Ignored and missing expression for a function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a function which takes a parameter, then compares two conditions.

One is checking if user_preference column has like '%CDN%' and another is user_name equal to the parameter that we took as input.

If those two conditions are successful needs to return 1 else 0. Below is the code block that I'm going to put in a package.

```
create or replace function check_status(p_user_name in varchar2) return number is
ln_value number;
begin
SELECT into ln_value (CASE WHEN user_preferences like '%CDN%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Value FROM emp_users WHERE user_name=p_user_name;
return ln_value;
end;
/
```

when I'm trying to execute pl/sql block in sql developer it is returning below errors. Could you please help me to resolve this.

```
Error(3,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(3,12): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your SELECT statement in the wrong order, try

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN user_preferences like '%CDN%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  into ln_value
  FROM emp_users 
 WHERE user_name=p_user_name;
```

Comment: Awesome... it's working... but I've a small query... I just wanted to print the value of ln_value. I added set serveroutput on and dbms_output.put_line(ln_value); but its not printing anything. Any idea why its working like this.